# GAS: deploy time based trigger app

Tags: google-apps-script

I wrote a custom GAS that reads some emails and manipulates them.  It uses the time based trigger to run.  I want to know if there is a way to "deploy" a specified version of this where the time based trigger still runs, but I can still work on new code changes in the apps script editor (running it manually) and then deploy that new version (that runs by time triggered) when it is ready?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into add-ons:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/